# Many values insertion from checkbox only last value is inserting in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to insert many values from checkbox but only the last value is inserting to database.

HTML CODE:

```
 <?php

  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fix_in_time");
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `material` WHERE id > 0");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['tipo'];?>" name="Tipo" id="Tipo"><label><?php echo $row['tipo'];?></label><br>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

There is the PHP CODE:

```
    $Sala = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Sala']);
    $Descricao = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Descricao']);
    $Tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Tipo']);
    $Data = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime('-1 hour'));

    if(empty($_POST['Sala']) || empty($_POST['Descricao'])|| 
    empty($_POST['Tipo'])){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Por favor 
    preencha os campos!');window.location.href='../index.php';</script>";
    exit();
  }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if (!empty($_POST['Tipo'])) {

            foreach ((array)$Tipo as $Tipo) {

                $query = "INSERT INTO `relatorios` (Data, Sala, Descricao, Tipo) VALUES ('$Data', '$Sala', '$Descricao', '$Tipo')";

                     mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should execute your query in every loop.

Comment: I am a bit noob , still learning xD

Comment: still inserting last value only

Comment: Change the name attribute of your input from   `name="Tipo"` to   `name="Tipo[]"`

Comment: now there is an error:     $Tipo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Tipo']);

Comment: Can you edit your question and past all the PHP code ?

Comment: yeah i'll do it

Comment: there is the edit on code

Answer (score 0):

In your html code change input tag to:
`<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['tipo'];?>" name="Tipo[]">`.
If you append tag name with `[]`, then this post variable in php will be an array. I've removed tag id because it should be unique, not sure if you need it, but if you do, then make it unique.

And your php code should look something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['Tipo']) && is_array($_POST['Tipo'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['Tipo'] as $Tipo) {
             $TipoEscaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Tipo);
             $query = "INSERT INTO `relatorios` (Tipo) VALUES ('$TipoEscaped')";
             $success = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
             if (!$success) {
                 //handle mysql error
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working but is it normal the values are inserting in diferent rows, like is it possible to make them insert in the same row?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Depends on how you want to store `Tipo` in your database. For example, you can store it as json encoded string, like so `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, json_encode($Tipo))`. Or you can have multiple columns for each `Tipo` value, eg. `INSERT INTO \`relatorios\` (Data, Sala, Descricao, Tipo_01, Tipo_02, ...) VALUES ...`

Comment: not working with json_encode and using (Tipo_01, ...) is not good for me because I  am selecting from database the "tipo" values to show them on checkbox! I am noob correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you want to use json_encode, you don't need to iterate over `Tipo` values, just encode whole array. `if (!empty($_POST['Tipo']) && is_array($_POST['Tipo'])) { $TipoEscaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, json_encode($_POST['Tipo'])); $query = "INSERT INTO \`relatorios\` (Tipo) VALUES ('$TipoEscaped')"; }`

Comment: You are correct that using multiple columns won't work if those values are fetched from db and written there dynamically. But if they are static, known values, then you can store them in php as well and it can work